# Decimal expansion program running very slow for large inputs

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, math, bigdecimal

I am writing a program to calculate the decimal expansion on the number `103993/33102` and I want to print out all of the trailing decimals depending on what number the user inputs. It runs quickly for all number up to `10^5` but if input `10^6` to program takes around 5 minutes to print out an answer. How can I speed things up? I have tried two different approaches one using `BigDecimal` and the other using strings and neither one is working efficiently.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {
    // BigDecimal num1 = new BigDecimal(103993);
    // BigDecimal num2 = new BigDecimal(33102);
    String repNum = "415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316";
    // pw.println(num.toString());
    String sNum = "3.1";
    // pw.println(repNum.length());
    int cases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int dec;
    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        sNum = "3.1";
        dec = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        if (dec == 0)
            pw.println("3");
        else if (dec <= 52) {
            sNum += repNum.substring(0, dec - 1);
            pw.println(sNum);
        } else {
            while (dec > 52) {
                sNum += repNum;
                dec -= 51;
            }
            sNum += repNum.substring(0, dec - 1);
            pw.println(sNum);

        }

        // pw.println(num1.divide(num2, dec,
        // RoundingMode.FLOOR).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `dec` and `cases`?

Comment: dec is the number of decimals you are expanding to and cases is if you want to print out the decimal expansion of the number in multiple ways, Ex if I input 2 4 6 it would print out the number expanded to the 4 decimal then it would print it out again expanded to the 6th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a long string of digits just print out the digits. For example:

```
        while (dec > 52) {
            System.out.print(repNum);
            dec -= 51;
        }
        pw.println(repNum.substring(0, dec - 1));
```

Creating a long string in a loop by concatenating is really bad for performance because strings are immutable. The program spends all its time creating new strings, one longer than the other, and copying characters from the old to the new, essentially implementing [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm).

Comment: he could also use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`

Comment: Thanks I always forget that these Strings are immutable and super slow